# Writing to a file from multiple threads at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, file-io

I want to write a large amount of data (say upto 10 GB or more) into a single file using multiple threads. My current idea is to use offset based techniques - say there is 10GB of data to be written to a file and there are 10 threads that write to this file, the first thread writes the first 1GB, the second writes the second next 1GB and so on, all at the same time. Is there a way to do so in .net core?

Comment: Open the file multiple times with the correct `FileShare` option. Though do remember  that your bottleneck will likely quickly become the disk as you add more threads.

Comment: MemoryMappedFile may also be useful here, but I echo what @DiplomacyNotWar is saying: you're likely just going to swamp the IO available on the drive